# Java if else in a lambda expression

Tags: java, if-statement, lambda

I am trying to use a lambda expression to evaluate to true or false on whether a input parameter to a method has a certain character '*' at the end of the string; as an input to a constructor to an object. im sure this is way off, but this is what i was trying to do before i looked around the web and saw some referring to using streams, but I'm not sure how or if they would work for this situation:

```
public void addPermission(String permission, String resource){
    permissions.put(new Permission(permission, 
()-> {if (permission.charAt(permissions.size() - 1) == '*') return true; }));
}
```

any input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your lambda expression is missing an else case (or a final return), see this example:

```
public void addPermission(String permission, String resource){
  permissions.put(new Permission(permission, ()-> {
    if (permission.charAt(permissions.size() - 1) == '*') 
      return true;
    return false;
  }));
}
```

Note that this would not compile if `permissions` is a Map, because the signature of `Map.put` is not compliant.

Another simplification (beyond those already mentioned by others):

```
public void addPermission(String permission, String resource){
  permissions.put(new Permission(permission, ()-> permission.charAt(permissions.size() - 1) == '*'));
}
```

The type of the given lambda should be a `FunctionalInterface` with no argument and result `Boolean`, e.g. `Supplier<Boolean>`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you *need* to use streams for this? Homework, bet, whatever?

**If you don't**

A plain old checking on the String with the `endsWith()` method would suffice.

```
public void addPermission(String permission, String resource){
    permissions.put(new Permission(permission, permission.endsWith("*")));
}
```

**If you want to play around with lambdas**

You can provide a way to *tell* the constructor what type of checking it needs to do in order to fill in that flag.

*Constructor:*

```
public Permission(String permission, Predicate<String> checker) {
    this.permission = permission;
    this.flag = checker.test(permission);
}
```

*Caller:*

```
new Permission(permission, (p) -> p.endsWith("*"));
```

Comment: there is no need, i was just trying to figure out some way to put some way to decide a boolean in the arguments rather than use if else in the method body. your way works great!